# Stack Overflow logo is missing in the blog

Tags: bug, design, blog, logo

Logo is missing in the [Stack Overflow blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/).

> [image: Logo missing]

When inspecting the element, I can see the below `<svg` code for the logo, but it is not displaying.

```
<svg role="img" class="so-icon so-icon-logo" 
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     aria-label="Stack Overflow Logo">
     <use xlink:href="#so-icon-logo"></use>
</svg>
```

Seeing the below console error in Chrome browser:

> [image: console error]

in plain text:

> Failed to load https://zgab33vy595fw5zq-zippykid.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/stackoverflow/assets/svg/output/symbol-defs.svg: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'https://stackoverflow.blog' is therefore not allowed access.

**System Configurations:**

OS: Windows 10 Pro
Google Chrome: Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Mozilla Firefox: 62.0
Zoom: 100%

Comment: Strange [Logo is Visible in FF 61.0.1 (64-bit)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjQPi.png)

Comment: No-Repro on FF 62.0 on Mac HS 10.13.4. The BLOG part was loaded way faster though. Logo was the last thing to render on the site.

Comment: Failed to load https://zgab33vy595fw5zq-zippykid.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/stackoverflow/assets/svg/output/symbol-defs.svg: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'https://stackoverflow.blog' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Unsafe attempt to load URL https://zgab33vy595fw5zq-zippykid.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/stackoverflow/assets/svg/output/symbol-defs.svg from frame with URL https://stackoverflow.blog/. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Comment: The social media icons in the sidebar are also missing as they are included in the same file that is failing to load.

Comment: Can reproduce with FF 62.0 (Win10). Console says `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at [...]. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘*, *’).`

Comment: I can repro on FF 62.0 on MacOS 10.12.6

Comment: CDN seems to send two but identical `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers.

Comment: For me (on FF Dev 63.0b8) the response for `symbol-defs.svg` doesn't actually seem to arrive, but I don't see an error and the logo is actually displayed...? Weird stuff going on...

Comment: Reproducible in Firefox Nightly 64.0a1. (An earlier comment said 63.0a1, which was incorrect.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently the issue has been fixed. Now the Stack Overflow icon is displaying in the blog.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: SO Blog with logo]