# Meta question closed as no-repro after bug was fixed

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, close-reasons, closed-questions

I'm looking at [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374362/stack-overflow-logo-is-missing-in-the-blog?rq=1) in particular. One of the moderators closed the question, giving the reason that the problem could no longer be reproduced.

However, aren't most MSO bug questions like this? A user asks a question regarding a bug/issue about the site. Then, hopefully, the bug will get fixed. None of the other questions like this that I have come across get closed because the problem cannot be reproduced. (Obviously, it cannot be reproduced: the bug is fixed!)

So, am I missing something as to why that question was closed with that reason?

Comment: If a bug has been fixed, then it stands to reason it can no longer be reproduced. I don't see anything wrong with closing the question for that reason.

Comment: @cs95 But aren't most bug questions going to be fixed? That would be a LOT of closed questions if they were. I can't find another example where a question was closed because it could no longer be reproduced *after* the bug was fixed.

Comment: 1) Not every question on bugs will be fixed (see all the questions on the mobile apps, for instance), 2) Just because not every solved question on a bug is closed does not imply it is wrong to close them. It just means nobody's gotten to it yet.

Comment: @cs95 Right, but the question I linked was talking about a bug. That bug was then fixed, and *then* the question was closed as off topic. Unless there's another reason for this besides the fact that the bug was already fixed?

Comment: You're asking the same questions. The answer is the same. You'll probably hear the same thing from Yvette.

Comment: There are currently 195 non-deleted questions that are [tagged \[bug\], are closed, and are not duplicates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbug%5D+%5Bstatus-completed%5D+closed%3Ayes+duplicate%3Ano+is%3Aq). So much for "can't find another example where a question was closed because it could no longer be reproduced after the bug was fixed", maybe if you tried looking harder. Granted, these questions usually end up getting deleted once they've been closed long enough and have accrued enough delete votes.

Comment: @TinyGiant Ok, point taken. But, are you saying that all the other questions that *aren't* closed even after the bug was fixed should be closed then? Because there are many more questions that fit this scenario. So I guess my question is: why are some questions closed but some are not, even though the bug is fixed on all of them?

Comment: Because those doing the curating haven't gotten around to those questions yet.

Comment: @TinyGiant That explanation wouldn't make sense seeing that there are [almost 1500 questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=Relevance&q=%5bbug%5d%20%5bstatus-completed%5d%20closed%3ano%20duplicate%3ano%20is%3aq) with the scenario.

Comment: And how many deleted questions are there in this scenario?

Comment: If a question is tagged with one of the status-*  tags I wouldn't bother closing them. Only bother if there is no action on it at all and it can no longer be reproduced. It only becomes an issue that needs immediate action if bug reports get linked to while it is 100% clear for every observer that the bug report is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 4):

Closing a question isn't a punitive action towards its author, but a maintenance action intended to keep the site clean of posts that [no longer] have a useful value. While it was reported in good faith, there isn't any reason to keep this bug report open now, as it no longer reproduces (since it was already fixed).

Perhaps retagging the question with [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) would have better reflected the situation, but ultimately, it wouldn't have changed the fact the question was (rightfully, IMHO) closed.

Comment: The tagging vs closing comes down to be a bit of a philosophical discussion. I'd say closing as not reproducable is fine - nobody did anything about this, and it now works. Could have been a deliberate action at some point but for something different, might have been a bit random that it didn't work in the first place. Whatever the case, no effort has been spent *specifically* on this task and it's now working. A `status-completed` seems more appropriate if the issue was deliberately addressed.